# Personal Code Project Only Works Sometimes

Tags: python

I wrote this code because I'm just starting out and wanted to practice a little bit. This code only works 1 out of every 10 times I try to run it. I wrote it in Jupyter Notebook.

When it doesn't work I get the `NameError: name 'oatcalories' is not defined.` Sometimes it says `'eggcalories`' is not defined as well.

How do I make sure it works 100% of the time?

Here it is:

```
while True:

    one = input("What are you eating for breakfast? (Enter one item at a time and 'done' when done)\n")

    if one == "done":

        print ("Done")

        break

    if one.lower() == "eggs":
        quantegg = input("How many eggs? ")
        eggcalories = (int(quantegg) * 78)
    elif one.lower() == "oatmeal":
        quantoat = input("How many servings of oatmeal? ")
        oatcalories = (int(quantoat) * 120)
    elif one.lower() == "avacado":
        quantav = input("How many avacados: ")
        avcalories = (int(quantav) * 120)
    elif one.lower() == "toast":
        quantoast = input("How many pieces of toast?: ")
        toastcalories = (int(quantoast) * 70)
        butter = input("Did you add butter?")
        if butter.lower()[0] == "y":
            quantbut = input("How many servings of butter?: ")
            butcalories = (int(quantbut) * 102)
        elif butter.lower()[0] == "n":
            butcalories = (int(quantbut) * 0)
    else:
        pass

break_total =  eggcalories + oatcalories + avcalories + toastcalories + butcalories
print ("Total calories for breakfast:",break_total)
```

This newbie appreciates your help!

Comment: I don't think you want that break in there.

Comment: define default values if you don't input them at runtime, e.g. `eggcalories = 0`

Comment: Find a rubber duck and ask him why `oatcalories` is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't defining any of the variables used in the `break_total` line at the very bottom. If your code was like this, it should work fine:

```
eggcalories = 0
oatcalories = 0
avcalories = 0
toastcalories = 0
butcalories = 0

while True:

    one = input("What are you eating for breakfast? (Enter one item at a time and 'done' when done)\n")

    if one == "done":

        print ("Done")

        break

    if one.lower() == "eggs":
        quantegg = input("How many eggs? ")
        eggcalories = (int(quantegg) * 78)
    elif one.lower() == "oatmeal":
        quantoat = input("How many servings of oatmeal? ")
        oatcalories = (int(quantoat) * 120)
    elif one.lower() == "avacado":
        quantav = input("How many avacados: ")
        avcalories = (int(quantav) * 120)
    elif one.lower() == "toast":
        quantoast = input("How many pieces of toast?: ")
        toastcalories = (int(quantoast) * 70)
        butter = input("Did you add butter?")
        if butter.lower()[0] == "y":
            quantbut = input("How many servings of butter?: ")
            butcalories = (int(quantbut) * 102)
        elif butter.lower()[0] == "n":
            butcalories = (int(quantbut) * 0)
    else:
        pass

break_total =  eggcalories + oatcalories + avcalories + toastcalories + butcalories
print ("Total calories for breakfast:",break_total)
```

The cause for error was because you were trying to add things that you hadn't set yet, so when you tried to add them the interpreter didn't know what you were referencing.